# pythonic way to find the max length of multiple sets intersection?

Tags: python, set

I wanted to get the subset of maximum length of intersection of each subset intersects by the total elements, I would like to know how to code in a simple pythonic way? Thanks a lot if someone can help.

```
max_subset = max(subsets, key=len(elements.intersection(e) for e in subsets))

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Sorry for the confusing, I was trying to implement the greedy algorithm solving the Maximum Coverage Problem. For each step, after excluding the current chosen subset, I want to find the subset which cover the most uncovered elements. To find this subset, I need to intersect the remained subsets with the universe set, among these uncovered intersections, the longest one would be chosen. The result of subsets should cover the maximum number of elements in the universe set, with minimum number of elements in the internal intersections.

Thanks again for everyone of you!

Comment: An example would help so we understand what you are looking for. Please see [mcve].

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you'd like to achieve. Subset is set created from elements of other, initial set. The bigger subset, the bigger intersection it have with initial set. So if you're doing intersection with initial set it's just pointless, as all you need is measure number of element of each subset to know which has biggest intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Except calling len on generator, you seem to have another, logic error in your code. Let's say, that you have some set `elements`:

```
elements = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

and you have **subsets** of this set, let's say:

```
subsets = [{'a', 'b'}, {'a'}, {'c'}]
```

...where **subset** is a set, that is created from elements of `elements` set. 
Then, subset of biggest intersection (which means: the one that has biggest number of elements in common with `elements` set) is the one that has biggest number of elements at all. So:

```
max_subset = max(subsets)  
# and that is {'a', 'b'}
```

Mind the fact, that only in set of all subsets of set `elements` you have subset that is "greatest subset" and it is always `elements` itself. In other case, there might be situation like this:

```
subsets = [{'a', 'b'}, {'b', 'c'}]
```

And there are two `maximum` subsets, but there is not `greatest` subset. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element) for reference.

But if you're not interested in comparing something else than subsets of initial set, so let's say that you have some set `other_elements` that looks like this:

```
other_elements = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

And list of set's that you want to compare with it looking for the one with maximum intersection:

```
list_of_sets = [{'a', 'b', 'x'}, {'c', 'z'}, {'c', 'd', 'e', 'w'}]
```

The proper way to do this is:

```
max(list_of_sets, key=lambda x: len(elements.intersection(x)))
```

...which result is: `{'c', 'd', 'e', 'w'}`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
mainset = {1, 2, 3, 4}
subsets = [{1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {1}]

max(map(len, map(mainset.intersection, subsets)))  # 3
```

Sometimes nested `map` can get confusing, in which case there are some alternatives.

Compose functions:

```
from toolz import compose
max(map(compose(len mainset.intersection), subsets))  # 3
```

List comprehension:

```
max(len(mainset.intersection(subset)) for subset in subsets)  # 3
```

Comment: I'd say that solution to OP's answer should find a set in result instead of number of elements, but it's actually not completely clear.

Comment: @erhesto, agreed. It's not entirely clear. Counter-intuitively, for questions like this we might need to edit the question after an answer is accepted!